# How to loop through attribute values in Jade?

Tags: javascript, pug

I've made a mixin for the [picture element](http://codepen.io/niallobrien/pen/yyjQyQ) (uses Picturefill.js) but would like to now create one to use img srcset with sizes.

```
<img srcset=”large.png 1200w, medium.png 600w, small.png 350w”
sizes=”(min-width: 600px) 600px, 100vw” alt=”My mug”>
```

How can I loop through the object I'm passing into the mixin and use each image as a value for srcset? Thanks in advance.

Comment: so the snippet is you desired output, right? what's your desired input, how you would like to call it (with which parameters, objects)?

Comment: Please see the link to the picturefill mixin above.

Comment: still not clear what you want. Provide what your desired input is and your desired output.

Comment: I've yet to settle on the exact desired input format, but I expect to pass the paths and desired sizes for each image, much like in the mixin I linked too. I just simply cannot figure how to output each of these values within the one attribute (srcset) - the same functionality will be needed for the sizes attribute.